# Longest Word made from Smaller Words

Tags: language, open-ended

**Objective:** Find the longest word, which can be made from concatenation smaller words.

**Rules:**
* Words (and smaller words inside) must be findable at dictionary.com
* Punctuation (for example ') does not count as part of the smaller word
* No numbers
* Must be done in English
* Must contain at least 3 smaller words

**Best:**
30 letters:

> Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism

made from the 3 words:

> Pseudo, Pseudo , hypoparathyroidism

*Answerer:* TroyAndAbed

Comment: what about overlap? or adding an s to make the plural form?

Comment: To make it more challenging/interesting, I suggest you disallow prefixes and suffixes...

Comment: Plurals are fine. Prefixes/Suffixes are fine. Overlaps are not.

Comment: why only english? in german there would be words like: "Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz"
a word made of "Rindfleisch", "etikettierung", "überwachung", "aufgaben", "übertragung" and "gesetz".
It's the name of a Law in "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern".

Comment: @Sebu Because idk German and English solutions are more interesting since I speak it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 letters:

> [Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism)

made from the 3 words:

> [Pseudo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pseudo?s=t), Pseudo , [hypoparathyroidism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypoparathyroidism?s=ts)

Also with 28 letters a non-medical word:

> Antidisestablishmentarianism

Made with :

> [Anti](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anti?s=t), [disestablishment](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disestablishment?s=t), [arianism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arianism?s=t)

Comment: Is "arianism" a word?

Comment: @rand - No, it's conjoined suffixes. If we're going to do that, why not make it antidisestablishmentarianistic for a nice round 30

Comment: @randal'thor Yes it's a word : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arianism?s=t

Comment: @user12365 arianistic exist but not antidisestablishmentarianistic

Comment: You aren't using it in that way. You're using it as -arian (being of the belief of something) -ism (acting on something).

Comment: then, what about "being of the belief of acting on a thing"? I know some people that truly believe they are acting on something, without really doing anything. ;P

Comment: @user12365 Yes, in antidisestablishmentarianism the meaning is not the same as in arianism alone but it's a concatenation of world, so the answer is valid.

Answer (score 3):

18 letters:

> counterprogramming: counter, program, ming 
>  unfortunately countercountermeasures (22 letters!) wasn't found in dictionary.com :(

Some words off the top of my head:

13 letters:

> nevertheless

12 letters:

> forevermore, nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is valid, but the word is

> [Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)

45 letters!

Which can be divided in:

> [Pneumo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pneumo) [no](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/no) [ultra](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ultra) [microscopic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/microscopic) [si](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/si) [lic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lic) [o](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/o) [volcano](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/volcano) [coniosis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coniosis)

Also, this can be divided as:

> [Pneumo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pneumo) [no](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/no) [ultra](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ultra) [microscopic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/microscopic) [sil](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sil) [ico](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ico) [volcano](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/volcano) [coniosis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coniosis)

And, in order to really abuse the spirit of the question, this can be divided even in this way:

> [P](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/p) [n](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/n) [e](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/e) [u](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/u) [m](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/m) [o](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/o) n o [u](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/u) [l](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/l) [t](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/t) [r](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/r) [a](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a) m [i](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/i) [c](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/c) r o [s](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/s) c o p i c o s i l i c o [v](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/v) u l c a n o c o n i o s i s

> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

Comment: Abreviations and acronyms aren't "words"

Answer (score 0):

I got

> pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

Words:

> pneum ono ultra microscopic silico volcano coniosis

May seem a little sketchy but it’s still valid. (Btw if your sketchy about Ono then https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ono)